# Twilio - Record a queued call

Tags: xml, node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-api

I'm using NodeJS to write a voice demo with Twilio. Using the [`<enqueue>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) an incoming call is placed in a queue like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="/wait.xml">support</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

On the wait.xml, I pause and wait for the second client to take the call from the queue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">Connecting to representative</Say>
    <Pause length="100"/>
    <Leave/>
</Response>
```

When the second client is initiated it uses `<Dial>` to dequeue the call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial record="record-from-answer" action="./record" method="GET">
        <Queue>support</Queue>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

All is working as expected except the call recording. I use the same principle when calling a `<client>` and that works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code is fine. I just tested. How do you determine that the call recording is not working? You should see the recording on the voice logs for the first client.

Comment: If for some reason you aren't seeing the recording on the logs, you can contact support - https://www.twilio.com/help/contact